# Why was session_store.rb removed in Rails 5.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 5.1 removes the `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file.  The [upgrading guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-5-0-to-rails-5-1) doesn't mention it.  Can someone explain why it was removed and what we should do with our existing file?  My current file looks like the following:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store(
  :cookie_store,
  :key => '_foo_session', # any value
  :secure => Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?, # Only send cookie over SSL when in production and staging
  :http_only => true # Don't allow Javascript to access the cookie (mitigates cookie-based XSS exploits)
)
```

Comment: Not sure why it was removed, but the `session_store` config is still valid. You could add it to your application config, or better would be to add it to it's own initializer. Everything in your initializers folder is loaded, so it doesn't matter if they have removed it from the boiler plate, it will still be included and work.